# How do I remove all files to be committed from the SVN commit list?

Tags: svn, commit

I accidentally created a problem by committing three different files in the same directory:

- GetUspsPostage.php
- GetUSPSPostage.php
- getUSPSPostage.php

I only want to commit GetUspsPostage.php. So I deleted the other files. But since they got added to svn, when I try to commit, svn gives me this error:

svn: E155010: 'C:\Users\Chris\dev\Projects\HyperSpace\svn\library\My\Action\Helpers\getUSPSPostage.php' is scheduled for
 addition, but is missing

To make matters worse, I just discovered that Windows 8 has no file name case sensitivity (?????) So when I try to create the missing file by copying another file with the name of the missing file, Windows reports that the file already exists (the file in question is named GetUspsPostage.php) and do I want to overwrite it. This makes it impossible to create the missing files.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: try svn delete filename then commit

Comment: I tried: C:\Users\Chris\dev\Projects\HyperSpace\svn> svn delete .\library\My\Action\Helpers/getUSPSPostage.php
D         library\My\Action\Helpers\GetUSPSPostage.php
C:\Users\Chris\dev\Projects\HyperSpace\svn> svncommit "Endicia live testing/fixes"

C:\Users\Chris\dev\Projects\HyperSpace\svn>svn commit --password #### -m "Endicia live testing/fixes"
svn: E155010: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155010: 'C:\Users\Chris\dev\Projects\HyperSpace\svn\library\My\Action\Helpers\getUspsPostage.php' is scheduled for
 addition, but is missing

Comment: Your suggestionn worked. I had to deal with my confusion over the many similarly named files, but once I got that cleared up, I had a successful commit. Thanks!

Comment: no problem. In that case I add it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell svn that you have deleted the file. Then commit your changes.

try:

```
   svn delete <filename>
```